# instabug text alignment wrong

Tags: android, instabug

I recently installed the instabug sdk (8.0.0), and when I run my app with the sdk , some of the textviews with text alignment end, now appears aligned to left.

There is something in instabug that change app the styles ?

Comment: They fixed in version 8.0.3

Answer (score 2):

This is fixed as of version 8.0.3.